# Curve tools: is there an add-on to join overlapping curves?

Tags: bezier-curves, add-on

In a "Curve" object that contains several non-continuous curves, is there an add-on to join overlapping segments together, like remove doubles does in mesh editing?
Explanation: merge two non-continuous segments with two control points in the same place so they become one unique segment!

I have this solution: I move one control point, then select the second contol point and press <kbd>F</kbd> to create a new segment that connects the two together. Then I remove the previously moved control point with <kbd>X</kbd> and both segments become one unique segment!

I can add a new add-on with this process, but I want to know if this command already exists.

Comment: You can join two segments by selecting the end vertices of each and pressing `F`. Joining two vertices is harder . . . I'll have to look it up

Comment: No I have just try it: with F you link the two vertices with a invisible segment with himself and the normal are multiples. I want a unique joined segment with 2 normals by vertex only, not 4 normals!

Comment: Eh, what? It will create a new segment, joining them into one continuous curve.

Comment: I don't think there is a tool to do what you are describing. It seems like it would be a useful add-on.

Answer (score 1):

There is no function that does this. If there were it would be Merge (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>) as can be done with vertices in a mesh object. Ideally this command should be coded into Blender natively without needing an add-on as it's such a minor operation. It would only be possible with two open-ended points though, and maybe that's the reason it hasn't been included thus far.

I suppose having an error message appear at the top of the screen when the points are not open-ended is one approach; another is breaking an existing segment in favor of forming the new one.

Comment: Thanks, I havn't seen your reply since.....Yes (Alt M) with curve is may be the solution.....byebye.

Answer (score 0):

YES (Alt + M) in Curve edit don't exist in Blender 2.79 last release!

[image]

Or may be removed since a lot of time.....may be.

I want make an add-on about this for 1 curve object or between 2+ Curve objects...

It's not normal that "Split" function exist but not the opposite!!!!

I understand :

1. : the point must be at the ends of each segments.
2. : be at the same globale position.

======================================================

EDIT: I have the solution to code:

1. Select several curve objects.
2. All selected curve object will be converted in mesh objects.
3. Merge all selected mesh objects in one mesh
4. Go to edit mode, select all vertices and "Remove double".
5. Separate > by loose parts
6. With all selected object "convert to Curve object" one by one.

This is the roadmap...

Comment: Is this an answer?